# Have the Rep requirements for Mod Tools suddenly changed?

Tags: bug, reputation, moderators, 10k-tools

This morning I didn't have Mod Tools on AE, this afternoon I get a banner saying I do, and they do seem to be there. I'm currently at 4,309 rep and according to the Recent Activity page I've only gained 10 rep so far today.

Pretty sure that last time I looked Mod Tools on the parent site still needed 10K (they're much lower on Meta, I've had them here for a while).

Can't see any new Stackoverflow/Exchange blog posts yet, was this a deliberate change for still in beta sites, or just a bug that's happening on my account?

Comment: definitely not an isolated incident, this happened to me as well

Comment: The [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq) for AE now lists wildly different rep levels than it used to. They don't line up with any of the levels in the [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) blog post, either, but that makes it seem like it might be deliberate.

Comment: Well, while in beta and trying to gain momentum, there are far too few users who have the ability to do "useful" tasks. There are the diamond mods and then a huge drop-off in abilities. We can't do it all; we need your help. This is a welcome change, I think.

Comment: Agree, it's a good idea during beta, probably would have been more worthwhile in the long period where Bryan was the only person here with over 2K rep. Rather than now where there's at least a handful of non-mods who've had Edit All and Vote to close privileges for a bit (as those were previously at 2k and 3K).

Comment: I just got Tools as well, with no notification.  Strange.

Comment: OK, just got the notification.  Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

I asked the other StackExchange moderators and they say that the [mod tools appear for 2k rep](https://android.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) on beta sites.  Otherwise I'd say the alert is just being wonky of telling you about the tools.

Comment: Mod tools were always supposed to be 2k for beta sites, but the other rep levels look different than [when they were last discussed on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/). Vote to close, for example, looks to have dropped from 1k to 500.

Comment: I think they were like that early in the beta period, but got changed around the time WebApps migrated. Perhaps in error. We've also been in beta longer than the "standard" 90 days and perhaps they didn't account for that. Obviously, something has been fixed.

Comment: This has definitely changed in the last day, I wasn't getting the "Tools" link at the top of the page on the main site until this lunchtime.

Answer (score 1):

something may have been off with the rep reqs in the past.

Here is a screenshot of all rep reqs compared:

[image]

Comment: Heej you don't have a nice ♦ here @Sam!

Comment: yeah ... I should fix that ... also we just made a change to retag and create new tag levels so the screenshot is a bit out of date

Comment: @SamSaffron Who *are* you?